# TypeError in Django view while using F expressions in queryset annotations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have a Django view that handles search functionality in my application. It filters questions and codes based on a user's query and calculates relevance scores using Django's F expressions. However, I'm encountering a TypeError when trying to use the `F` expression in my queryset annotations.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my `SearchResultView:

```
class SearchResultView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'codeisc/search_result_page.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user'] = self.request.user if self.request.user.is_authenticated else None
        query = kwargs.get('query')
        keywords = query.split()

        questions = Question.objects.filter(Q(short_description__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query))
        for keyword in keywords:
            questions = questions.annotate(
                relevance_score=(
                        F('short_description__icontains', keyword) +
                        F('description__icontains', keyword)
                )
            )
        questions = questions.order_by('-relevance_score')
        context['questions'] = questions

        codes = Code.objects.filter(Q(short_description__icontains=query) | Q(code_text__icontains=query))
        for keyword in keywords:
            codes = codes.annotate(
                relevance_score=(
                        F('short_description__icontains', keyword) +
                        F('code_text__icontains', keyword)
                )
            )
        codes = codes.order_by('-relevance_score')
        context['codes'] = codes

        return context
```

When I try to run it I get this Error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: F.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

and my models:

```
class Code(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Code_Author")
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default="No Description Provided")
    code_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ("TXT", "TextFile"),
        ("PY", "Python"),
        ("JS", "Javascript"),
        ("C", "C"),
        ("CPP", "C++"),
        ("CS", "Csharp"),
        ("JV", "Java"),
    ]
    type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default="TXT")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.short_description}:{self.author.username}"


class Question(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Question_Author", null=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, default="No Description Provided")
    description = models.TextField(null=False, default="No Description Provided")
    code = models.ManyToManyField(Code)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.short_description}:{self.author.username}"
```

Comment: Exactly what is `F('short_description__iexact', keyword)` supposed to do?

Comment: Edited the question, the edited version is supposed to find a case-insensitive containment match

Comment: I would strongly advise to work with a search engine tool, not wrap some search engine yourself. This will be inefficient (`__icontains` often will fall back to "linear" search), and poor quality, since not all keywords are equally "powerful". A search engine like elastic search will pre-process content, build indexes, and will try to determine what keywords contain most information.

Comment: I get it, I'll do it, but still i wanna know what is wrong with this?

Comment: replace `F(...)` with `ExpressionWrapper(Q((...)), models.IntegerField())` moreover you will have to sum these all up, not make multiple `.annotates` since then you get a "clash".

Comment: Would you explain a bit more briefly, in answer form if possible, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

As conveyed by the error message, you gave too mush argument to a `F` object.
`F('short_description__icontains', keyword)` is invalid.

`F` allows you to reference a column or an alias of the current queryset. For instance:

```
Question.objects.filter(short_description=F("description"))
```

Will get you all question with the same short_description and description

Comment: Will I be able to still sort them by `relevance_score`???
And I don't insist on using F(), I wanna make it work without using 3rd party search engine

Comment: If you want to attribute some point you can use case/when expressions `Case(When(short_description__icontains=keyword, then=SHORT_DESCRIPTION_SCORE), default=0) + Case(When(description__icontains=keyword, then=DESCRIPTION_SCORE), default=0)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll do more research on it